# How to count values in an array

Tags: r, count

How to count values in a multiset?
I have a dataset and i want to write a function for a frequency table. So that i now which abnormalities are present in my data. The data is an array and looks like this:

```
             GSM288217   GSM288219 GSM288221
ch1_500001   NA          NA        NA       
ch1_1500001  "Imbalance" "Balance" "Balance"
ch1_2500001  "Imbalance" "Balance" "Balance"
ch1_3500001  "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_4500001  "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_5500001  "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_6500001  "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_7500001  "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_8500001  "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_9500001  "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_10500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_11500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_12500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_13500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_14500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_15500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_16500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_17500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_18500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
ch1_19500001 "Imbalance" "LOH"     "Balance"
```

Now i want the function to check per ROW how much a certain abnormality is present in the data.  I started with:

```
detection<- function(abnormality) {
  freqcount<-rep(0,nrow(abnormality))
  if(assayDataElement(abnormality, 1)=="LOH")#TRUE & FALSE?? Need frequency
    {freqcount<-freqcount+1
     }          
  return(freqcount)

}
```

So every time there is LOH present on the rows of the data it should give the numbers of LOH present in that row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need

```
length(which(assayDataElement(abnormality, 1)=="LOH"))
```

or for each row individually:

```
count <- function(x,what) length(which(x==what));
apply(assayDataElement(abnormality, 1),1,count,"LOH");
```

Comment: Something like that indeed, but it should do this per row and not for the entire data.